# Why can't I curry a react component?

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I've been getting started with react-redux and finding it a very interesting way to simplify the front end code for an application using many objects that it acquires from a back end service where the objects need to be updated on the front end in approximately real time.

Using a container class largely automates the watching (which updates the objects in the store when they change). Here's an example:

```
const MethodListContainer = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return <MethodList {...this.props} />},

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchAndWatch('/list/method')},
  componentWillUnmount(){
    if (isFunction(this._unwatch)) this._unwatch()},

  fetchAndWatch(oId){
    this.props.fetchObject(oId).then((obj) => {
      this._unwatch = this.props.watchObject(oId);
      return obj})}});
```

In trying to supply the rest of the application with as simple and clear separation as possible, I tried to supply an alternative 'connect' which would automatically supply an appropriate container thus:

```
const connect = (mapStateToProps, watchObjectId) => (component) => {
  const ContainerComponent = React.createClass({
    render(){
      return <component {...this.props} />
    },

    componentDidMount(){
      this.fetchAndWatch()},
    componentWillUnmount(){
      if (isFunction(this._unwatch)) this._unwatch()},

    fetchAndWatch(){
      this.props.fetchObject(watchObjectId).then((obj) => {
        this._unwatch = this.props.watchObject(watchObjectId);
        return obj})}
  });
  return reduxConnect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ContainerComponent)
};
```

This is then used thus:

module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps, '/list/method')(MethodList)

However, `component` does not get rendered. The container is rendered except that the `component` does not get instantiated or rendered. The `component` renders (and updates) as expected if I don't pass it as a parameter and reference it directly instead.

No errors or warnings are generated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different variable name for the `component` parameter.

```
const connect = (mapStateToProps, watchObjectId) => (MyComponent) => {
  const ContainerComponent = React.createClass({
    render() {
      return <MyComponent {...this.props} obj={this.state.obj} />
    }
    ...
    fetchAndWatch() {
      fetchObject(watchObjectId).then(obj => {
        this._unwatch = watchObject(watchObjectId);
        this.setState({obj});
      })
    }
  });
  ...
}
```

I think the problem might be because the component is in lower case (`<component {...this.props} />`). JSX treats lowercase elements as DOM element and capitalized as React element.

*Edit:*

If you need to access the `obj` data, you'll have to pass it as props to the component. Updated the code snippet

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This made no difference though.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the way you structure the HOC aside from what I pointed out. I assume the `reduxConnect` is an alias of the redux connect `import { connect as reduxConnect } from 'react-redux';`

Comment: It is. I can't see the problem either which is why I ended up posting the question (after much experimentation). The workaround in my own answer has got me by but I will have to modify it in order to pass through (and augment) mapStateToProps.

Comment: Are you trying to use the `obj` returned by `fetchAndWatch` method inside the component being wrapped? if so, you'll need also pass it to the component too aside from the `{...this.props}`. `<MyComponent {...this.props} obj={this.obj} />`. You'll also have to update your `fetchObj` then to save the `obj` to a variable.

Comment: Yes but the 'mapStateToProps' sets up the obj prop and updates it once the async fetch completes (because connect subscribes to the store) so it does not need explicit assignment in the fetch.

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround rather than an explanation for the error:

In connect_obj.js:

```
"use strict";
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {actions} from 'redux/main';
import {gets} from 'redux/main';
import {isFunction, omit} from 'lodash';

/*
A connected wrapper that expects an oId property for an object it can get in the store.
It fetches the object and places it on the 'obj' property for its children (this prop will start as null
because the fetch is async). It also ensures that the object is watched while the children are mounted.
 */

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({obj: gets.getObject(state, ownProps.oId)});

function connectObj(Wrapped){
  const HOC = React.createClass({
    render(){
      return <Wrapped {...this.props} />
    },

    componentDidMount(){
      this.fetchAndWatch()},
    componentWillUnmount(){
      if (isFunction(this._unwatch)) this._unwatch()},

    fetchAndWatch(){
      const {fetchObject, watchObject, oId} = this.props;
      fetchObject(oId).then((obj) => {
        this._unwatch = watchObject(oId);
        return obj})}});
  return connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(HOC)}

export default connectObj;
```

Then I can use it anywhere thus:

```
"use strict";
import React from 'react';

import connectObj from 'redux/connect_obj';

const Method = connectObj(React.createClass({
  render(){
    const {obj, oId} = this.props;
    return (obj) ? <p>{obj.id}: {obj.name}/{obj.function}</p> : <p>Fetching {oId}</p>}}));
```

So `connectObj` achieves my goal of creating a project wide replacement for setting up the connect explicitly along with a container component to watch/unwatch the objects. This saves quite a lot of boiler plate and gives us a single place to maintain the setup and connection of the store to the components whose job is just to present the objects that may change over time (through updates from the service).

I still don't understand why my first attempt does not work and this workaround does not support injecting other state props (as all the actions are available there is no need to worry about the dispatches).